# Vuetify Offset not creating any offset

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have a block of code with the recommended layout as per the vuetify docs and for the life of me can't figure out why whatever I do my `<v-flex>` does not respond to `offset`. Below is the code with a screenshot:

```
 <v-layout v-show="expanded"  v-for="(row, index) of queryCopy.query_parts" :key="index" align-baseline justify-start row fill-height wrap>
          <v-flex  offset-xs7 sm1 mx-3>
            <v-select
              class="whtsp-nowrap"
              label="Condition"
              v-model="row.condition"
              :items="options.condition"
              item-text="display"
              item-value="value"
              @input="isRowComplete"
            ></v-select>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex sm1 mx-3>
            <v-select
              label="Field"
              :items="options.fields"
              item-text="display"
              item-value="value"
              v-model="row.field"
              @input="isRowComplete"
            ></v-select>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex sm1 mx-3>
            <v-select
              label="Operation"
              v-model="row.operator"
              :items="options.operator"
              item-text="display"
              item-value="value"
              @input="isRowComplete"
            ></v-select>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex sm2 mx-3>
            <v-text-field
              label="Search Value"
              v-model.lazy="row.value"
              @input="isRowComplete"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex shrink>
            <v-btn @click="removeQueryRow(index)" class="mr-0"small icon>
              <v-icon color="grayDE">clear</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex>
            <v-btn  @click="addQueryRow" class="ma-0" small icon>
              <v-icon color="primary">add</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
```

my question is about the first flex box that has `offset-xs7` the screen is `sm` so it should apply (I tried changing it as well to no avail).[image]
The condition dropdown should be offset to be under "query conditions"

Comment: Did you check out css styles of the element? is the class offset-xs1 applied? Maybe the style will be overwritten from something else? The offset-xs7 should add something like  "margin-left: XX.XX%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mx-3 will overwrite offset, so you can't use them both

Comment: Thank you, this did work although now I have another issue, where offset-sm1 is too much for alignment purposes and pl/ml-5 is too little...any ideas?